# Downloading data from two Worksheets of a URL with an Excel File

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd, import-from-excel

I am looking to gather all the data from the penultimate worksheet in [this](http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls) Excel file along with all the data in the last Worksheet from "Maturity Years" of 5.5 onward. The code I have below currently grabs data from solely the last workbook and I was wondering what the necessary alterations would be.

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd 

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)

xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
df = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-1], header=None)

print df
```

I was thinking of using `glob` but I haven't seen any application of it with an Online Excel file.

**Edit**: I think the following allows me to combine two worksheets of data into a single Dataframe. However, if there is a better answer please feel free to show it.

```
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import os
import xlrd 

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'
socket = urllib2.urlopen(url)

xd = pd.ExcelFile(socket)
df1 = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-1], header=None)
df2 = xd.parse(xd.sheet_names[-2], header=None)

bigdata = df1.append(df2,ignore_index = True)
print bigdata
```

Comment: That all looks pretty respectable to me. Is there something not working?